# where is my Ubuntu 12.04 data?

Tags: data-recovery

One day I got minimal bash like line error and I tried to solve it by following instruction given at google and I was unable to repair grub and then when I tried to recover my data. I am unable to recover my Ubuntu data.

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 both in my laptop. When I boot live cd to check my data I found my home empty. Where is my data? I am very worried. I am research student and I lost all my research in a second. I could not recover my data and repair Ubuntu. Please help me.

Comment: can you provide the exact error?

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -la` in your home directory when mounted with live cd.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if we had a list of the commands you were using, or some link to some of the processes you were using (from Google) to try to recover your data.  None of the grub command options would interfere with actual data on your drives.  The grub commands are boot options.  It would use sectors on the drives that are reserved for booting.

Even an option to reinstall Ubuntu using the live disk would leave the areas that contains your person data untouched, unless you used and option to reformat a drive or partition.

So, unless you specifically chose a format option you should be able to locate your data by browsing your drives and partitions.  By the way, this would be from a real install, not from a `Wubi` install, whereas Ubuntu would actually be running as a program under Windows using a virtually created disk.  If that is the case, you would do something different from the steps provided below.

- **Browsing drives and partitions using GUI**

From the Live CD (ideally one of the later Ubuntu LTS versions, I'm using 14.04) bring up gnome-disk-utility.  You can do this by typing `disk` in the Launch search button.

On the left column of the program window you will see a list of the drives attached to your computer.  Start from the top and select one.  Once you have selected a drive you will see the various partitions on the right column under the `Volumes` section.  They will be listed as Partition 1, Partition 2, Partition 3, etc.

Mount the partitions one by one by selecting the `Partition #`.  Click on the play icon to mount it if it's not mounted.  Then below the Volumes section click on the `Contents` link specified by `Mounted at` to bring up the volume.

Look for the folder you specified by your home folder on that drive.  By default it would be call `/home/[userid]`.  The userid would be the name you selected for login when you performed the install.

Do this for each of your drives and partitions.

You can also right click on the `Mounted at` link and click `Copy Link`.  Then with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> open a terminal window then use the `find` command to search for your userID or any specific file that you remember having created on your data drive.

You can go to a volume by right typing cd and pasting the link to the terminal.  You would have to remove the `file://` prefix and have a command like the example below:

```
$ cd /media/ubuntu/4fed9bc1-07b0-45a2-a384-b24213e2d09e
$ sudo find -name userid
```

- **Browsing drives and partitions using cli**

From a terminal window type this command to see your connected drives and partitions:

$ cat /proc/partitions

This command will give you a list of partitions labeled similar to `sda1`, `sda2`, `sdb1`, `sdb2`, etc.

The one by one use this command sequence to search each partitions:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ cd /mnt
$ sudo find -name userid
$ sudo umount /mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

If your home directory, by chance, is not encrypted, you will be able to access it and copy the data.

First, start Ubuntu live CD, and the open the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, enter the command: .`df -h`
Look at the output to see if there is `/media/device_name`
Go to the directory, you should find your real home directory, e.g, `/media/device_name/home/username`
If you have any question, feel free to leave a comment.

Good luck!